# Is it possible to delete My site of a particular user automatically in moss 2007 when this user is deleted from AD( Active Directory)?

Tags: 2007

Is it possible to delete My site of a particular user automatically  in moss 2007 when this user is deleted from AD( Active Directory) ?

Also is it possible to delete all my sites created once in moss 2007?

Thanks.

Comment: Is programming an option for you?

Comment: yes Janis, if programming is last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably straightforward way to approach this would be to set up Site Use Confirmation and Deletion on your MySite web app. (Central Adminstration --> Application Management --> Site Use Confirmation and Deletion)

This will notify owners of sites that have not been used for a specified period of time to confirm that they are still required. If they do not respond to the notification (e.g. because they've left or been deleted), the site will expire and will be removed.

It's not quite what you're after, but it's a close approximation.

Comment: thanks SHug.It is good option to delete My Site but it may cause issue if any user is on leave for 90 days(specified time period for notification) and he is not accessing his My Site during this period.

Comment: You can tweak the time period, but I agree it's not quite what you were after. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have not come across an automatic/already developed way of doing this.

You would have to monitor the profiles missing from an import and then pass those values through for deletion. Do you really have that much churn that you need to do it? Would the value of doing some custom work equal or exceed the benefit of removing the My Site?

You may want to have a read of this article on the scenarios around My Sites:
http://philwicklund.com/whitepapers/Documents/My%20Site%20Concerning%20Scenarios%20Study%20and%20Strategy.pdf

Chris